# Why won't Flash Player on Chromium work?

Tags: raspbian

I have installed Chromium on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspian) with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` and I followed the instructions from this site to attempt to get flash player running: http://linuxologist.com/01general/howto-chromium-browser-on-linux-with-flash/

ie I just downloaded `libflashplayer.so`, placed it in `/usr/lib/` then make a symlink to it in `/usr/lib/chromium/plugins/`. then i open Chromium like so:

```
chromium --enable-plugins --enable-greasemonkey --enable-user-scripts --enable-extensions
```

from the command line. However, flash player is still not recognised. The version of flash player I downloaded was from softpedia in tar, which i had to untar.

Has anyone managed to get this working? If so, then what extra steps were required?

**Update**

[Alex](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/86/alex-chamberlain) requested I run `file`, so here it is:

```
$ file /usr/lib/libflashplayer.so
libflashplayer.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Comment: You are aware that Linux can run on multiple platforms and you need one fitting your hardware.  In this case an ARM cpu.

Comment: Even if you get it running, flash will **not run well** on the Pi. I don't think you should put any more effort into getting it to work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yeah i've been using linux for a while now so i am familiar with it. i wasn't sure if the libflashplayer.so file would have support for arm - i guess i was a bit hopeful there...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain ah right! haha i'll update the Q

Comment: @Jivings the pi has hardware accelleration for h264.  It could be made to work relatively well for video playing.

Comment: @mulllhausen Linux is a large area, and if you only use it on an x86-platform you do not learn of the "hey, wrong CPU"-problems.  Well, you do now :)

Comment: @mulllhausen What are you using flash player for? Videos, websites or flash development?

Comment: @Haskeller just for having a fully functional chromium browser (mainly watching youtube). not for development or anything like that...

Comment: @mulllhausen There are other ways to watch Youtube...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## ARM vs x86

Intel processors used by desktops are 32/64-bit architectures, generally known as x86 and x86_64.

ARM processors, which is used by the Raspberry Pi, also use a 32-bit architecture, but it is incompatible with x86. Therefore, x86 libraries will not run on the Raspberry Pi.

### How do I know you have an x86 library?

I asked you to run

```
file /usr/lib/libflashplayer.so
```

which output

```
libflashplayer.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

`Intel 80386` tells us it was compiled for x86.

### Do Adobe release an ARM version of Flash?

Yes and no. There are versions available for a lot of Mobile platforms, but I believe it is being deprecated (*citation needed*) and I haven't seen it available for ARM Linux. (*citation needed*)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: @Jivings: That's your opinion! ;-)

Comment: Can't edit cos its too small, but I believe that should be "deprecated" not "depreciated" (http://linguisticszone.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/depreciate-or-deprecate.html).

Comment: @JonEgerton So I do.

Answer (score 5):

## Gnash

> Gnash is a free SWF movie player. It is available as a stand-alone application or as a plugin for several popular web browsers. It supports playing media from a disk or streaming over a network connection. Some popular video sharing sites like YouTube are supported on a wide variety of devices from embedded ones to modern desktops.

### Installation

Gnash should be in the distributions' repositories.

**Debian**

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnash
```

**Arch**

```
$ sudo pacman -Sy gnash
```

### Configuration

It should Just Work, but I haven't tried it yet. Will do soon.

#### References

1. [Gnash User Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/manual/gnashuser.html)

Comment: I don't think you meant the `-y` flag for `pacman`. That synchronizes the package list, something that is unnecessary when installing software.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore Or I did...

Comment: It is unnecessary to synchronize the package list when installing software. Most people will do this when updating the system instead.

Comment: It didn't work form me with Chromium + Gnash.

Answer (score 4):

I think Adobe did not release any flash plugin of ARM Linux.

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

I don't know where do you get the "libflashplayer.so", but i guess it is X86 or X64 version.

Comment: Hi lxp121 Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. Usually the best answers are supported by facts and citations. Currently this is not a complete answer, can you please improve it?

Comment: @jivings this is a widely known fact.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The original answer did not include the link or 3rd line.

Comment: It did not need one, as the fact is widely known.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution,install [android](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1700) on a chrooted environment. That way android can play flash because of the [google chrome support](http://www.mobilemag.com/2012/02/07/google-chrome-arrives-for-android-ics-4-0/) and the [flash plugin](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5250/adobe-updates-flash-111-for-android-40) . Still a long way until android hits the raspberry pi.

Alternatives to Flash(If your only using it for video play back)

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)(My favourite choice)

```
#Arch Linux
pacman -S vlc
#Debian
apt-get install vlc
```

Install this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jldiailifbdkepgpcojllmkbakleicab) .
Then open VLC goto Tools > Preferences (Click All) > Interfaces > Main interface > Check Web and save. Restart and your done!
**OR**

```
vlc -I http
```

[Lightroom](http://lightspark.github.com/)

Comment: i installed vlc the other day as its my favourite media player and i wanted to test out a few avis. i didn't know about the chrome plugin though - that's probably the best solution to watching online flash movies (if it works well) - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OS maemo/meego(based on debain) supports flash player on nokia n900(with ARM Cortex A8) microB Browser(based on Mozilla Firefox):
http://natisbad.org/N900/n900-commented-hardware-specs.html

maemo download link:
http://tablets-dev.nokia.com/
next link is needed to generate IMEI for N900 to download image files:
*ttp://www.nokiaport.de/tacdatabase/index.php?s=imeitools&lng=
i hope this info can help the raspberry pi community

thanks for reply if there is a chance to get it run on raspberry

Comment: I don't exactly understand your post. Can you clarify it a little?

Answer (score -2):

Are you using Google Chrome? I think that's short for Chronium. If so, I read that Google Chrome cannot run correctly on an ARM processor. Hope this helps.
Try finding a different browser, use Epiphany or your pre-installed browser, or find another one using

> sudo apt-get install

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think your command is missing something. Feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: apt-get install what exactly? You're missing the package to install.

Comment: The latest versions of Chromium (45 at time of writing) will only work on the RPi 2 Models without (I believe) any hardware acceleration, older Q&A in this SE community may refer to it working on the older Pis but that is an ancient version 22 that is not around now I think.